# Get value from object without knowing the key

Tags: javascript

I have `item.124bn1353v = 'foo'`

However the `124bn1353v` key is dynamically generated but I need to get its value `foo`.
How can I get the `foo` assuming that we have only one property in the `item` ?

Comment: try this http://www.syger.it/Tutorials/JavaScriptIntrospector.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one property set on the `item` object this will assign it to the variable `foo`:

```
var foo;
for (var prop in item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        foo = item[prop];
    }
}
```

Example JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VDyUe/

Comment: Thanks, is `.hasOwnProperty()` necessary, why?

Comment: In newer browsers there's also `Object.keys(item)`, which gives you all the "own" property names of an object. So `item[Object.keys(item)[0]]` would get the value of the "only" property, if there really is just one.

Comment: @Diolor it just ensures that the property is actually set directly on the object. See here for details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty